# My Jersey Spring Boot 1.5.2 project doesn't recognize FormDataMultiPart

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jersey, multipartform-data, multipart

I tried to add `FormDataMultiPart` to my Jersey Spring Boot project.  I am using Spring Boot 1.5.2 and the Spring Boot Jersey Starter.

I tried adding the full import `org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataMultiPart`, but it is not found.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `spring-boot-starter-jersey` Maven dependency does not include `jersey-media-multipart`.  You need to add it to your `pom.xml`.  On the other hand, Spring Boot does define a `jersey.version` property so you can use that to keep the versions in sync.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!--  Multipart not included in Spring Boot.  jersey.version defined by Spring Boot. -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Once you add the `jersey-media-multipart` dependency to Maven, the `FormDataMultiPart` class can be found.

Comment: How to achieve the same in gradle?